# Online code browser for GitHub

Tags: github, ide, editor, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a code navigator that I was using to browse code located on GitHub. It looks like VSCode. It was very simple of use : no signing in, and you just need the url of the GitHub project to view the code, with hypertext links to browse from file to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was is [Sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/)? It appears to be based on VSCode, [here](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/Microsoft/vscode/-/blob/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L229:6)'s the VSCode repo itself viewed from there:

[image]